# Problem with Infrasonic Quartet and ALSA

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I`ve got **Infrasonic Quartet** PCI Soundcard and use Ubuntu 13.04.
The card has 2 analog stereo outputs. I use both outputs to connect my headphones and speakers  to each other. 
But I suddenly cannot manage the outputs with alsamixer: I can mute only Output 1/2. 
Output 3/4 is always "On" whatever I change in Alsamixer.
Here is my /proc/asound/cards:

```
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 45
 1 [Quartet        ]: ICE1724 - Infrasonic Quartet
                      Infrasonic Quartet at 0xc080, irq 18
```

Can someone tell me how to make alsamixer manage both outputs ?

UPDATE.
Here is the **amixer -c 1 scontents** output:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono: Playback 249 [98%] [61.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM 1/2',0
  Capabilities: pvolume cvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255 Capture 0 - 164
  Front Left: Playback 165 [65%] [-3.78dB] Capture 155 [95%] [14.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 165 [65%] [-3.78dB] Capture 155 [95%] [14.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PCM 3/4',0
  Capabilities: pvolume cvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255 Capture 0 - 164
  Front Left: Playback 169 [66%] [-3.57dB] Capture 155 [95%] [14.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 169 [66%] [-3.57dB] Capture 155 [95%] [14.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PCM In 1/2',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'An In 1/2' 'An In 3/4'
  Item0: 'An In 1/2'
Simple mixer control 'PCM In 3/4',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'An In 3/4' 'IEC958 In'
  Item0: 'An In 3/4'
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'PCM Out' 'H/W In 0' 'H/W In 1' 'IEC958 In L' 'IEC958 In R'
  Item0: 'PCM Out'
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Output',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'PCM Out' 'H/W In 0' 'H/W In 1' 'IEC958 In L' 'IEC958 In R'
  Item0: 'PCM Out'
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 1/2',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Line In 1/2' 'Mic' 'Mic + Low-cut'
  Item0: 'Line In 1/2'
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 1/2 to Monitor 1/2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 1/2 to Monitor 3/4',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 3/4',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Line In 3/4' 'Hi-Z'
  Item0: 'Line In 3/4'
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 3/4 to Monitor 1/2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Analog In 3/4 to Monitor 3/4',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Coax Output Source',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'IEC958' 'I2S'
  Item0: 'IEC958'
Simple mixer control 'H/W',0
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'PCM Out' 'H/W In 0' 'H/W In 1' 'IEC958 In L' 'IEC958 In R'
  Item0: 'PCM Out'
Simple mixer control 'H/W',1
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'PCM Out' 'H/W In 0' 'H/W In 1' 'IEC958 In L' 'IEC958 In R'
  Item0: 'PCM Out'
Simple mixer control 'Multi Track Internal Clock',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '44100' '48000' '88200' '96000' '176400' '192000' 'IEC958 In' 'Word Clock 1xFS' 'Word Clock 256xFS'
  Item0: '44100'
Simple mixer control 'Multi Track Rate Locking',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Multi Track Rate Reset',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Output 1/2 to Monitor 3/4',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Output 3/4 to Monitor 1/2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Phantom Power',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
```

Could anybody explain what this output means? Why playback channels are mono?

Here is my alsamixer screenshot:[image]
Output 3/4 is off but both outputs are playing sound now. And I can`t switch it off.

Comment: What is the output of `amixer -c 1 scontents`?

Comment: What is the desires result? And what do you mean with "suddenly"; did it work previously?

Comment: @CL. It did not work previously and my "suddenly" was just for fun. The desires result is managing each output separately ( switch it on/off and manage its volume control). Now I can manage only 'output 1/2'. The other one is always on whatever I do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Thanks to **CL.** I tried to solve it with PulseAudio.
First of all I installed `pavucontrol`. Then I made `~/.asoundrc` (Alsa config file) and pasted the following into the file :

```
pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}
ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}
pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}
ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

It makes PulseAudio to be used by default.
And after that I can manage both outputs of the soundcard separately with `pavucontrol`. Now it`s possible. Finally Otput 1/2 is named Analog Output , Output 3/4 - Digital Output in Volume Control.
I used  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Advanced_ALSA_Configuration for information.

Answer (score 1):

The ICE1724 chip was originally designed for big multi-channel cards where all inputs and outputs are used at the same time, so it is not possible to use the outputs as completely separate devices.

The `Mono` describes the mixer control itself, not the audio device.

`alsamixer` shows the mixer controls implemented by the hardware.
The Windows driver implements additional controls by doing an additional software processing step in the driver.
It might be possible to do the same in Linux with some audio server like PulseAudio, as described in [Splitting front/rear](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Splitting_front.2Frear):

> Connect speakers to front analog output and headphones to rear output. It would be usefull to split front/rear to separate sinks. Add to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:
>
> ```
> load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=speakers remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
> load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40 channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right   channel_map=front-left,front-right
> ```
>
> (replace `alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40` in the sound card name shown from `pacmd list-sinks`)

Comment: So, but why is it possible on Windows? The same chip, the same card. Why can`t I configure ALSA to get manage outputs on Linux?

Comment: Splitting front/rear did not help me, but thanks to you I have found the way!